# PHP: link a Block

Tags: php

quick question, i want to link the BLOCK1 to another page. Is it possible? do anyone got a solution? i have tried abit and my brain is going mad T_T. there are 5 other blocks that i which to link to other pages aswell.

this is the code below:

```
 <div class="midrow_block axn_block1">
            <div class="mid_block_content">

              <!--BLOCK1 IMAGE-->
              <?php if(!empty($optimizer['block1_image']['url']) && empty($optimizer['block1_img_bg'])){   ?>
                  <div class="block_img"><img src="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['height']; ?>" /></div>
              <?php } ?>

             <div class="block_content">
                  <h3>
                  <?php echo do_shortcode( $optimizer['block1_text_id']); ?>
                  </h3>
                  <?php echo do_shortcode($optimizer['block1_textarea_id']); ?>
              </div>


            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <!--BLOCK1 END-->
```

Comment: Put an `<a>` around the whole block, what else?

Comment: tried that but it didn't work for some weird reason T_T

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `<a>`-Tag arount the block you want to link:

```
<a href="'your link here'"> <!-- start link here -->
    <div class="midrow_block axn_block1">
        <div class="mid_block_content">

          <!--BLOCK1 IMAGE-->
          <?php if(!empty($optimizer['block1_image']['url']) && empty($optimizer['block1_img_bg'])){   ?>
              <div class="block_img"><img src="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['height']; ?>" /></div>
          <?php } ?>

         <div class="block_content">
              <h3>
              <?php echo do_shortcode( $optimizer['block1_text_id']); ?>
              </h3>
              <?php echo do_shortcode($optimizer['block1_textarea_id']); ?>
          </div>


        </div>
    </div>
 </a> <!-- end link here -->
```

Or put it around any other part you want to have the link on. It's just basic `HTML` and has nothing to do with `PHP`.

Comment: well, the way above. i did it and nothing happend :/

Comment: with `nothing happend` it's hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry DocRattie, the <a href> seems to look good in the PHP put still the block doesn't get clickable. can't see what the error really is :/

Comment: Can you inspect it with something like firebug ans see if you can find any errors in there?

Answer (score 0):

here is the fullcode of the block. i missed to copy the top of it:

```
       <?php if ((!empty ($optimizer['block1_text_id'])) || (!empty ($optimizer['block1_textarea_id']))  ) { ?> 


         <div class="midrow_block axn_block1">
            <div class="mid_block_content">

              <!--BLOCK1 IMAGE-->
              <?php if(!empty($optimizer['block1_image']['url']) && empty($optimizer['block1_img_bg'])){   ?>
                  <div class="block_img"><img src="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $optimizer['block1_image']['height']; ?>" /></div>
              <?php } ?>

             <div class="block_content">
                  <h3>
                  <?php echo do_shortcode( $optimizer['block1_text_id']); ?>
                  </h3>
                  <?php echo do_shortcode($optimizer['block1_textarea_id']); ?>
              </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use with this JS

```
<div  class="midrow_block axn_block1" onclick="location.href='url'">content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $("div").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});
```

Comment: where do i place the JQuery? :o

Comment: in your page with in the head tag or your view file with in script tag<script> $("div").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});</script>

Comment: i put the script under 
<header> put it didn't work, i can't find the view file aswell T_T